# ApkAnalyser Build failure

Tags: java, maven

I  try to build ApkAnalyser Project as per in the doc using this link Click [here](https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/ApkAnalyser/blob/master/README)
I did step 1 and 2 as mentioned in Build steps it goes fine.But when i try to do step 3 it shows the error

```
Downloading: http://android-apktool.googlecode.com/svn/m2-releases/brut/j/dir/1.0/dir-1.0.pom 
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'brut.j:dir:pom:1.0' in repository android-apktool.googlecode.com (http://android-apktool.googlecode.com/svn/m2-releases)Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/brut/j/dir/1.0/dir-1.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'brut.j:dir:pom:1.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://android-apktool.googlecode.com/svn/m2-releases/brut/j/util/1.0/util-1.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'brut.j:util:pom:1.0' in repository android-apktool.googlecode.com (http://android-apktool.googlecode.com/svn/m2-releases)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/brut/j/util/1.0/util-1.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'brut.j:util:pom:1.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://android-apktool.googlecode.com/svn/m2-releases/brut/j/common/1.0/common-1.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'brut.j:common:pom:1.0' in repository android-apktool.googlecode.com (http://android-apktool.googlecode.com/svn/m2-releases)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/brut/j/common/1.0/common-1.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'brut.j:common:pom:1.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 68 source files to /home/sarath/workSpace/CeriseCloud/ApkAnalyser/apktool/apktool-lib/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

/home/sarath/workSpace/CeriseCloud/ApkAnalyser/apktool/apktool-lib/src/main/java/brut/androlib/res/data/ResPackage.java:[24,16] error: package brut.util does not exist

/home/sarath/workSpace/CeriseCloud/ApkAnalyser/apktool/apktool-lib/src/main/java/brut/androlib/AndrolibException.java:[19,18] error: package brut.common does not exist

/home/sarath/workSpace/CeriseCloud/ApkAnalyser/apktool/apktool-lib/src/main/java/brut/androlib/AndrolibException.java:[24,39] error: cannot find symbol

could not parse error message:   symbol: class BrutException
/home/sarath/workSpace/CeriseCloud/ApkAnalyser/apktool/apktool-lib/src/main/java/brut/androlib/res/decoder/ARSCDecoder.java:23: error: package brut.util does not exist
import brut.util.Duo;
```

I am new to maven.I have no idea to build the project.Please help me here!